# disabling email warning from itunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchkit, testflight

We have an automated process to push builds to itunesconnect for internal testing through testflight.  We supported a watchKit 1.0 app previously.  We made the decision to abandon those users and only support watchOS 2.  But we are getting an email warning from iTunes Connect.  Short of setting a spam filter rule in my email or just implementing watchkit 1, is there a way to turn off this email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got this warning and tried to remove it but came to conclusion that there are only 4 types of notifications described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW25) that you can manage. In all likelihood the `App Status` type of notifications is that you need but I think it's not worth it because it will switch off all status notifications.

Comment: I'm not happy with that answer but thank you for letting me know that I can't get from Apple what I want.